# Export Data to File

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a situation where i need to place a header line of information into a CSV file.

After which, i will need to append 3 queries, of varying column numbers, to this file.

Currently have this logic, but the `TransferText` line overwrites what i had placed in the file prior to it:

```
Dim fldr As String

Dim dlg As Office.FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With dlg
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select a Folder:"
    .Filters.Clear
    '.Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"

    If .show = True Then
        fldr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
GC dlg

'TODO: Remove after Debugging is complete
RaiseAlert "Folder chosen: " & fldr
'-----------------------------------------

Dim file As String
file = fldr & "\Export_DelaGet_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".csv"

'TODO: Remove after Debugging is complete
RaiseAlert "File: " & file
'-----------------------------------------

'TODO: OpenFile and output the header line
Open file For Output As #1
Print #1, """SYS"",""Some Data""" & vbCrLf
Close 1

'Output Query/View Results to file
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "MstPrc_Spec", "vwMasterPrices_Output", file, False
```

Would it be better for me to just Iterate through the query via RecordSet or am i missing something in TransferText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone else can provide me a better way of performing this, here is what i have so far.

```
Dim fldr As String

Dim dlg As Office.FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With dlg
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select a Folder:"
    .Filters.Clear
    '.Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"

    If .show = True Then
        fldr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
GC dlg

'TODO: Remove after Debugging is complete
'    RaiseAlert "Folder chosen: " & fldr
'-----------------------------------------

Dim file As String
file = fldr & "\Export_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".csv"

'TODO: Remove after Debugging is complete
'    RaiseAlert "File: " & file
'-----------------------------------------

'TODO: OpenFile and output the header line
Open file For Output As #1
Print #1, """SYS"",""Some Data""" & vbCrLf
Close 1

Open file For Append As #2
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, str As String

'Append MasterPrices
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("vwMasterPrices_Output")
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        str = """" & rst(0) & """,""" & rst(1) & """,""" & rst(2) & """,""" & rst(3) & """,""" & rst(4) & """," & Format(rst(5), "##0.00")

        Print #2, str

        'Move Next
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

'Append GroupPrice
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("vwGroupPrice_Output")
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        str = """" & rst(0) & """,""" & rst(1) & """,""" & rst(2) & """," & Format(rst(3), "##0.00")

        Print #2, str

        'Move Next
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

'Append GroupLocations
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("vwGroupLocations_Output")
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        str = """" & rst(0) & """,""" & rst(1) & """," & rst(2)

        Print #2, str
        'Move Next
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

GC rst
Close 2
```

Unfortunately the `TransferText` method performs a `File-Output` and not a `File-Append` operation.  So anything in the file prior to the `TransferText` is cleared and replaced with the output of the method.

Yes i had to have text qualifiers around Strings for the CSV.

Comment: Yes i built my own VB6 Collector....its a combination of `Set <var> = Nothing` (if object) and if RecordSet object `<var>.close`.  It takes a `ParamArray` parrameter so if i have a bunch i need to close out (per say), i can comma delimit them.